# Find routes in graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I'm trying to find all possible routes and then print to the user, but since I'm kind new to prolog, I'm having some trouble.

[image: graph]

I have to print all possible ways to go to G from A. This is what I have so far:

```
direct_path(pathA,pathB).
direct_path(pathA,pathC).
direct_path(pathB,pathD).
direct_path(pathC,pathE).
direct_path(pathC,pathF).
direct_path(pathE,pathD).
direct_path(pathE,pathG).
direct_path(pathF,pathG).

upward(X, Y):- direct_path(X, Y).
upward(X, Z):- direct_path(X, Y), upward(Y, Z).
```

This way I can check if it's possible to get from A to G, but how to I do to print this paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a third parameter to your `upward` predicate to store the path:

```
upward(X, Y, [X, Y]):- direct_path(X, Y).
upward(X, Z, [X | Rest]):- direct_path(X, Y), upward(Y, Z, Rest).
```

Test run:

```
?- upward(pathA, pathG, Path).
Path = [pathA, pathC, pathE, pathG] ;
Path = [pathA, pathC, pathF, pathG] ;
false.
```

So there are two different paths from A to G.